# dnx . ef command returns System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, npm, nuget, entity-framework-core

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 Tech Preview.

This is what I have for dnvm list:

> Active Version           Runtime Architecture Location
>   Alias
>   ------ -------           ------- ------------ --------                     -----
>          1.0.0-beta4       clr     x64          C:\Users\Jonas.dnx\runtimes
>          1.0.0-beta4       clr     x86          C:\Users\Jonas.dnx\runtimes default
>          1.0.0-beta4       coreclr x64          C:\Users\Jonas.dnx\runtimes           *    1.0.0-beta4       coreclr
>   x86          C:\Users\Jonas.dnx\runtimes
>          1.0.0-beta5-12021 clr     x86          C:\Users\Jonas.dnx\runtimes
>          1.0.0-beta5-12087 coreclr x86          C:\Users\Jonas.dnx\runtimes

This is the error I'm getting with dnx . ef:

> dnx : System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 
>   'DNXCore,Version=v5.0': At line:1 char:1
>   + dnx . ef
>   + ~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.InvalidO...,Version=v5.0'::String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>
> EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-beta4    EntityFramework.SqlServer
>   7.0.0-beta4    Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies 1.0.0
>   -beta4    Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook 1.0.0-beta4    Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google 1.0.0-beta4
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount 1.0.0-beta4
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter 1.0.0-beta4
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics 1.0.0-beta4
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity 7.0.0-beta4
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 3.0.0-beta4
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta4    Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers
>   6.0.0-beta4    Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS 1.0.0-beta4    Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener 1.0.0-beta4
>   Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles 1.0.0-beta4
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor 1.0.0-beta4    Microsoft.CSharp
>   4.0.0-beta-22816    Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc 1.0.0-beta4    Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json 1.0.0-beta4
>   Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets 1.0.0-beta4
>   Microsoft.Framework.Logging 1.0.0-beta4
>   Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console 1.0.0-beta4    Microsoft.Net.Http
>   2.2.29    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook 3.0.1    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader 14.0.0-beta4
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.1.0
>   System.Collections 4.0.10-beta-22816    System.Linq 4.0.0-beta-22816
>   System.Threading 4.0.10-beta-22816    WindowsAzure.Storage
>   4.4.1-preview
>
> Searched Locations:   C:\Users\Jonas\Dropbox\Visual Studio 2015
>   Projects{name}\project.json   C:\Users\Jonas\Dropbox\Visual Studio
>   2015 Projects\TestSite\src{name}\project.json
>   C:\Users\Jonas\Dropbox\Visual Studio 2015
>   Projects\TestSite\test{name}\project.json
>
> Try running 'dnu restore'.
>
> at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost.GetEntryPoint(String
>   applicationName)    at
>   Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost
>   host, String applicationName, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)

dnu restore returns these kinds of errors:

> dnu : npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies At line:1 char:1
>   + dnu restore
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm ERR! instal...ad dependencies:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   npm   ERR!  Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>
> npm   ERR!   argv  "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe"
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" 
>   "install"
>
> npm   ERR!   node  v0.12.4
>
> npm   ERR!   npm   v2.10.1
>
> npm   ERR!

npm debug log file has this:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@2.10.1
3 info using node@v0.12.4
4 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from C:\Users\Jonas\Dropbox\Visual Studio 2015 Projects\TestSite\package.json
5 error install Couldn't read dependencies
6 verbose stack Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Jonas\Dropbox\Visual Studio 2015 Projects\TestSite\package.json'
6 verbose stack     at Error (native)
7 verbose cwd C:\Users\Jonas\Dropbox\Visual Studio 2015 Projects\TestSite\artifacts\bin\TestSite\Debug\app
8 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
9 error argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
10 error node v0.12.4
11 error npm  v2.10.1
12 error path C:\Users\Jonas\Dropbox\Visual Studio 2015 Projects\TestSite\package.json
13 error code ENOPACKAGEJSON
14 error errno -4058
15 error package.json ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Jonas\Dropbox\Visual Studio 2015 Projects\TestSite\package.json'
15 error package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
15 error package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
16 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

I don't know where to start to fix the errors. I haven't found a suggestion that worked.

Thanks for your help.

---

UPDATE

I resolved it by installing bower and gulp. I don't know why I had to do it now as I never needed it in previous ef migrations on the same project.

Comment: [Please, write a better title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: Added error message type to the title. The full message will be too long...